# Reduce function does not work with an array of 3 or more object Elemetns

Tags: javascript

As title says, reduce does not work with 3 or more elements of array of object because it returns

```
undefined-Basket
```

Expected output:

```
Soccer-MMA-Basket
```

Here is my code with example data, Why this happened?

```
 const sports = [
      {
        name: "Scoccer",
      },
      {
        name: "MMA",
      },
      {
        name: "Basket",
      },
    ];

    const allSports = sports.reduce(
      (previousValue, currentValue) =>
        previousValue.name + "-" + currentValue.name
    );

    console.log(allSports);
```

Comment: return `{name:previousValue.name + "-" + currentValue.name}`

Comment: @dandavis close, but I'm looking return a string, not an object

Comment: well if you want to keep the logic-less callback, then you'll have to map the object array to a string array via something like `sports.map(x=>x.name)` in front of the reduce. otherwise you'll need a more complex reduce callback.

Comment: @dandavis The only thing you'd need in a "much more complex reduce callback" is either have a restructuring assignment (not sure the exact name) in the callback header (like `{name}`) or `.name` when you access the name property

Comment: @Samathingamajig: can you show how that reduce callback would work?

Comment: @dandavis the answer i posted ...

Comment: @Samathingamajig your reduce callback doesn't have "restructuring" and it has logic that has to eval every iteration. The assembly code for that is much longer than OP's reduce callback's code, thus it's more complex... I would also use `x=>x.name` for your map()'s callback to avoid repetition, but it all works for sure. cheers.

Comment: @dandavis Grammarly keeps auto"correcting" destructuring to restructuring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

> The first time that the callback is run there is no "return value of the previous calculation". If supplied, an initial value may be used in its place. Otherwise the array element at index 0 is used as the initial value and iteration starts from the next element (index 1 instead of index 0).

The arguments for the callback function are `(accumulator, current, index, array)`, and the optional second argument is the initial value of the accumulator. When no initial value is present, it skips to the second index with arr[0] as the initial value. In your case, you need to have an explicit initial value of "" since you return a string in each case and string doesn't have the property `.name`.

```js
const sports = [{
    name: "Scoccer",
  },
  {
    name: "MMA",
  },
  {
    name: "Basket",
  },
];

const allSports = sports.reduce(
  (output, currentValue, index) => output + (index > 0 ? "-" : "") + currentValue.name,
  "");

console.log(allSports);
```

However I would recommend doing this:

```js
const sports = [{
    name: "Scoccer",
  },
  {
    name: "MMA",
  },
  {
    name: "Basket",
  },
];

const allSports = sports.map(({name}) => name).join("-");

console.log(allSports);
```